# Bind a value to other in WPF UserControl

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding

I have an WPF UserControl that has a property IsSelected. In that control I have a Border(the control is circular, si I have a circle-Ellipse) around, that should appear only if the control IsSelected.

```
<GeometryDrawing>
    <GeometryDrawing.Pen>

        <!--   HERE ==> Thickness = IIF(IsSelected, 2, 0) -->
        <Pen Brush="blue" Thickness="2"/>

    </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
        <GeometryGroup>
            <EllipseGeometry x:Name="Border" 
                Center="0,0" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5"/>
        </GeometryGroup>
    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
</GeometryDrawing>
```

How can  I bind the pen's thickness?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a [Control Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773.aspx) with [TemplateBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742882.aspx). You will also need a [TypeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970913.aspx) that will transform boolean value into thickness integer.

Something like:

```
<Pen Thickness="{TemplateBinding IsSelected, 
                 Converter={StaticResource BooleanToSizeConverter}" />
```

Comment: ee.. could you be more specific? 
`<Pen Thickness="{TemplateBinding IsSelected? 2 : 0>}" .../>` like this?